# SKShapeNode.Get Radius?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skshapenode

Is it possible to get an `SKShapeNode`'s radius value?

The problem is, I need to create an identical circle after the user releases it, whilst removing the first circle from the view.

```
    SKShapeNode *reticle = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:60];
    reticle.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.3];
    reticle.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    reticle.position = CGPointMake(location.x - 50, location.y + 50);
    reticle.name = @"reticle";
    reticle.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addChild:reticle];

    [reticle runAction:[SKAction scaleTo:0.7 duration:3] completion:^{
        [reticle runAction:[SKAction scaleTo:0.1 duration:1]];
    }];
```

Then

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
....
    SKNode *node = [self childNodeWithName:@"reticle"];

    //take the position of the node, draw an imprint

    /////////Here is where I need to get the circle radius.

    [node removeFromParent];

}
```

How does one take the circle radius, so I can then say

```
SKShapeNode *imprint = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:unknownValue];
```

I've tried, making an exact copy of the circle with

```
SKShapeNode *imprint = (SKShapeNode *)node;
```

However, this still follows the animation where as I need it to stop, at the point it was at. I don't want to take a "stopAllAnimations" approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the shape node's `path` property to determine the bounding box of the shape with `CGPathGetBoundingBox(path)`. From the bounds, you can compute the radius of the circle by dividing the width (or height) by 2. For example,

```
CGRect boundingBox = CGPathGetBoundingBox(circle.path);
CGFloat radius = boundingBox.size.width / 2.0;
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `myVariable.path.boundingBox.width / 2`

Answer (score 1):

*Updated for Swift 5*

```
myVariable.path.boundingBox.width / 2
```